# Putting decorations onto a drone?

Tags: multirotor, under-250-grams, decorations

I want to jazz my quadcopter up a bit, maybe put some stickers or little sequins.

- Will these affect the flying capability of the drone, even though they aren’t that heavy?
- Will this affect balance?

Comment: Not a dupe, but strongly related   https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/1006/spray-painting-a-drone-what-to-look-out-for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So long as your additions are very lightweight compared to the drone - like stickers or paint - this should not have a significant effect the balance of your drone. However, you want to make sure that you do not cover any ventilation holes or heat transfer surfaces as this might affect the lifespan of those parts.

In the case of metallic additions (shiny stickers, sequins) it is good practice to keep these clear of the antenna as they may affect the radio performance.

You should avoid adding anything to the propellers or motors as these do need to be precisely balanced.

Comment: To add to that - place decor close to the centre of mass of the drone to minimise the shift in its centre of mass.

Comment: Very important to add: stickers on propeller and affect their balance thus cause vibration.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Kralc has mentioned, you also want to make sure that your decorations don’t vastly impact the aerodynamics of your aircraft.

Drones are flying bricks at the best of times - they don’t have the best aerodynamics, however you should try to be wary of the impact of large sheets. Anything that increases the cross sectional area will impact how the aircraft flies, and also how well it can cope with the wind.

Also make sure that your decorations are firmly stuck to your aircraft - if one comes loose it can get into the props and cause a crash.